# three finger gestures (swipe up and down) doesn't work in ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, touchpad, asus, multi-touch, gestures

Please help me!! I searched everywhere but this problem seems to be only mine! I can't use three fingers swipe up gesture for multi-tasking in any linux distros with gnome desktop. It works in windows and brings up the open windows but it doesn't work in linux for some reason. I tried installing synaptics, I tried using wayland and even touchegg app didn't help me. My laptop is Asus k53sd and the hardwares are fine

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. First of all 22.10 is not an LTS release. Did you check the settings? If you did it would be helpfull to mention those things in your question.

Comment: Ok, I installed ubuntu 22.04.1 and the problem persists. And there is no settings for gestures as far as I have seen. Do you think my touchpad's driver doesn't exist in linux's kernel?

Comment: We don't know what is "your touchpad". Do  other gestures work?

Comment: It's synaptics and scroll gestures with two fingers work, but three finger gestures doesn't work unlike windows